# Sarajevo to Budapest

Tags: public-transport, serbia, hungary, budapest, bosnia

Now that the Sarajevo-Budapest train has stopped running (and given that there's no direct bus) what is the best way to go between Sarajevo and Hungary? Someone suggested to start with a bus from Sarajevo to Novi Sad but in the main bus station I could see no such bus (maybe there's one from Lukovica/Istocno Sarajevo bus station?) Any other ideas?

Comment: [This might be an option](http://www.eurobusways.com/budapest-sarajevo-bus.html)

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything else available than this bus. Sources like Rome2Rio or the Deutsche Bahn do not offer anything else which is "reasonable".

Comment: Your best bet is probably to take whatever itinerary can find through Eurolines, even if indirect.  You might be able to cobble together a shorter-distance itinerary by going from small city to small city in a straight line, but that would almost certainly require more time.

Comment: If you can afford 200-300 dollars, you might consider flying: http://www.kayak.com/flights/SJJ-BUD/2014-10-07

Answer (score 5):

If you have plenty of time, you can take the night bus operated by [Croatia Bus](http://www.croatiabus.hr/index.php?lang=en), departing 22:00 in Sarajevo and arriving 06:00 in Zagreb. Then the train from Zagreb Glavni Kolod. at 09:57, arriving in Budapest 16:29. The price will be about 55€ (25€ for the bus and 30€ for the train).

Answer (score 3):

This answer comes super late, but these are my suggestions.
Take a bus to Belgrade, then either a bus or a train to Budapest from there (around 20-25 euro). To get you to Belgrade, take a bus from Istočno Sarajevo (around 25-30 euro return ticket). Novi Sad only has a train to Budapest (I think I paid 20 euro for the return ticket).
Another, more expensive option, is taking a flight from Sarajevo directly to Budapest. Without luggage it's about 50 euro (you may have one carry-on free, you should check on the Wizzair website). With luggage it's about 100 (ish) euros, maybe even cheaper. There's one or two flights per week.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wizz Air flies SJJ-BUD these days Monday and Friday.
2. Car share is a popular optinon. https://www.motar.eu/ and https://www.blablacar.com/